# Is manual object deletion possible in Java?

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection

In some languages like `Python`, there are ways by we can "delete" an object from the heap explicitly. As for example:

```
s = "This is a Test"
del s
```

Now, the object `s` cannot be used anymore. Now, my question is, can we do anything similar in `Java`? Yes, I know it is garbage collected, and that is a huge advantage in most situations, but what if I want to manually delete an object? By the way, does `del` in Python actually delete the object, or does it delete the reference variable? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why would you want to manually "delete" an object?  What do you think that would accomplish?

Comment: It wouldn't save anything and could introduce bugs.  For example the string literal exists in the string cache and you get the same object every time.  If you were to run the code above more than once and the string really had been deleted, you would have a serious bug.

Comment: Your premise is wrong. You cannot delete an object in Python. `del s` removes the name `s` but doesn't do anything to the object that it referred to. Of course, if it was the only reference, this makes the object eligible for garbage collection, but that's nothing special - `s = something else` has the exact same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Luiggi Mendoza has said you can not manually delete.How ever you can refer it to `NULL`.
To free the memory you can call `System.gc()` .But there is no guarantee that memory will be freed.
Before removing an object from memory Garbage collection thread invokes finalize () method of that object and gives an opportunity to perform any sort of cleanup required.

Comment: you're not deleting anything - you're just requesting that the garbage collector is run, and the JVM can ignore you.

Comment: @javaBeginner: It's really rare to need to write a `finalize()` method; it's really hard to write one correctly; and its very existence impedes garbage collection.  See http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/misc_slides/java_finalizers.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

> can we do anything similar in Java?

No.

At most you can nullify the object:

```
s = null;
```

This will mark the object for garbage collection, and when trying to use it (except when assigning a new value to it), you will get a `NullPointerException`.

```
s = null;
...
s.foo(); //this will throw a NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1):

in java for sure we cannot delete the object...but we can try with System.gc(); or if we want to lost the reference of a object we can set the value of object reference null; .. but after setting null value we can't access the object but it still remains in memory......

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to null all references to the object after which the object cannot be used anymore and will be deleted on next GC. But string constants objects like "This is a Test" are stored in a pool and are not deleted if even there is no reference to them.

Comment: Should highlight that storing nulls is usually not needed. Only reference fields or variables that are themselves reachable will keep anything alive, so only those would need to be nulled out or pointed at something else. That's why it's rare to see actual x = null; statement in code.

Answer (score 1):

The object will get deleted from heap once it goes out of scope. You can enclose `s` in the minimal possible scope where it is used. i.e. either enclose within a block of {} braces, or define a separate method where it is used

Comment: It's not true that objects cease to be reachable once they are out of scope.  Such objects have *method* scope from the point of view of reachability.  So `public void run() { {Object o = new Object(); System.out.println(o);} /* o can no longer be used but it still exists!  So the following is a memory leak! */ while(true) { try { Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE); } catch (InterruptedException e) { } } }` never cleans up o without an `o = null` before exiting the inner block.  Why this is so makes sense if you think about it in terms of the virtual machine and Java byte code instructions.

Comment: Jeremy. There is no memory leak in your example above, and nobody needs to store a null anywhere for that allocated object to go away. When you reach the while loop (in your example) o is out of scope. The object it referred to is no longer reachable and there is no way to access it or to to re-establish reachability to it. It is dead and gone, and the next GC will happily reclaim the space it had occupied as needed to satisfy some future allocations.

Comment: @GilTene, objects are reachable until the stack frame is exited, i.e. when the method exits.  Extra braces to create inner scope in methods are syntactic and do not affect the stack frame.  Thus the following two tests pass `@Test public void testNoGC() { WeakReference<Object> ref; { Object o = new Object(); ref = new WeakReference<Object>(o); } System.gc(); assertNotNull(ref.get()); } @Test public void testGC() { WeakReference<Object> ref; { Object o = new Object(); ref = new WeakReference<Object>(o); o = null; } System.gc(); assertNull(ref.get()); }`